# Using ROMs made for a specific device

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, custom-roms

I have a moto x 2013 Dev edition and got the unfortunate news yesterday that Motorola will not be updating my device to marshmallow, which I understand as an older device, but the specs of this phone can easily handle android m.

I am planning on flashing cyanogenmod onto the device, however I have 2 questions relating to that.

1) if I flash the device, will I still be able to use it as a development tool? I am working on learning the android API and having a physical device that I can test things on using the adb is essential.

2) this device has not received any device specific cyanogenmod ROMs in almost a year. Is it safe to load on a generic cm 13 ROM when it is released, or will it not support the device? (I am not concerned with the loss of the Motorola apps. Half of them are being discontinued anyway)

Comment: 1) True, 2) That's a speculative question. Ask CM for their plans of supporting the device. However, if your device hasn't received an official CM build since an year, then it is very unlikely that you would get an official build of Android Marshmallow. You may have to look for an unofficial build then. But that's all futuristic to talk about, something not useful to the site (IMO).

Comment: @firelord it seems there are a ton of ghost Roms that are still coming out for the device. (Forgive my ROM newbieness). Would this be a good alternative? And I'm guessing true means that it would still work?